# Are protected attributes available to parent classes in PHP?

Tags: php, oop

I know that protected attributes are available to subclasses when they are defined in a class, but are they available in parent classes? For example:

```
class My_Class {
    // Is $name available here?
}

class My_Subclass extends My_Class {
    protected $name = 'Henry';
}
```

Comment: Instead of writing a question you can try

Comment: No, there could be any number instances of any number of child classes with different values for `$name` - how would you determine which to use?

Comment: @u_mulder I think the fact that there's been so much difference of opinion in the answers to this question shows that it was worth asking. Don't you think?

Comment: @Steve The *execution context* determines that. I.e., whatever instance `$this` refers to at the time of calling any code.

Comment: @deceze Ah yes, that is true. I read the question as "available from **an instance** of parent class", which as it turns out was not what henry meant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Code which you write in the parent class *can* access that property if run in the context of a subclass. Made sense? Example:

```
class My_Class {
    public function test() {
        echo $this->name;
    }
}

class My_Subclass extends My_Class {
    protected $name = 'Henry';
}

$a = new My_Class;
$b = new My_Subclass;

$a->test(); // doesn't work
$b->test(); // works
```

Obviously (hopefully), instances of `My_Class` won't suddenly sprout a `name` property, so `$a->test()` *won't* work. Precisely because of that it's a very bad idea to make a class rely on properties which it doesn't define.

Visibility doesn't only relate to `$this` BTW, watch:

```
class My_Class {
    public function test($obj) {
        echo $obj->name;
    }
}

class My_Subclass extends My_Class {
    protected $name = 'Henry';
}

$a = new My_Class;
$a->test(new My_Subclass);  // Amazeballs, it works!
```

A parent class has access to the property if and when it tries to access it. That doesn't mean all parent classes suddenly get a copy of that property themselves.

Comment: That's because test() is inherited by My_Subclass so $name is never really in My_Class. Right?

Comment: Right. `$this` represents the *context* in which code is run, the object instance. An instance of `My_Class` doesn't have a `name` property, so `$this->name` doesn't exist. The same code in the context of another instance, i.e. if `$this` refers to an object which *does* have a `name` property, will work just fine. Actually, you *can* do `$a->name = 'Foo'` and it'll work just fine too. It doesn't matter where the property comes from, just that it's there.

Comment: My confusion comes from [here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php). To quote: "Members declared protected can be accessed only within the class itself and by inherited and parent classes."

Comment: Yes, it says that *parent classes trying to access that property* can do so. It does not mean that all parent classes will suddenly get a copy of that property themselves.

Comment: Thanks for the update. So, you've passed an object (My_Subclass) to test(). And because My_Subclass has access to $name, my name can be echo'd?

Comment: However, if nothing was passed to test(), then inside test(), something like this wouldn't be possible `echo $this->name;`. Am I following?

Comment: Right, I've just substituted `$this` for an object passed in as a parameter. Fundamentally both things work exactly the same. `$this` refers to the object the method was called on (i.e. in `$a->test()`, `$this` inside `test()` refers to `$a`). It's just an implicitly present reference to an object. *Explicitly* passing in an object as `$obj` is not fundamentally different.

Comment: That makes perfect sense. Thanks for explaining! :)

Answer (score 2):

The parent class has no information about its subclasses, so no, `$name` is not available in `My_Class`.

Edit: As @deceze points out correctly in a comment code in `My_Class` can access `$name`, but that only works if the object was instantiated from a subclass implementing that variable. Accessing the variable in the parent class will give an `Undefined Property` notice.

Also I would consider that bad style and architecture, but that's my opinion ;)

Comment: Not entirely correct. An instance of `My_Class` obviously won't have the property. That doesn't mean code in `My_Class` doesn't have access to the property at all.

Comment: @Cornelius My confusion came from [here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php). To quote: "Members declared protected can be accessed only within the class itself and by inherited and parent classes."

Comment: Yes, that describes what deceze corrected me on. I still think that's a crazy construct and shouldn't be supported by the language, but well, it is :-)

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes it 'can', **but you really shouldn't do it**

```
class A { 
    function set() {
        $this->v = 'a';
    } 
    function get() {
        return $this->v;
    }
} 
class B extends A{ 
    protected $v = 'b';
}
echo $b->get();//b
$b->set();
echo $b->get();//a
var_dump($b); //class B#1 (1) { protected $v => string(1) "a"}

$a = new A();
echo $a->get(); //Undefined property: A::$v
$a->set();
$a->get();//a
var_dump($a); //class A#2 (1) { public $v => string(1) "a"}
```

Answer (score -2):

No. "***protected***" *access modifier* makes any property and method to be visible from the derived class. This is what it is used for. But parent class never knows any information about the derived class.

For more information please see [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Access_modifiers) article.